# Phase transition detected using Raman spectra is not visible with XRD analysis

Tags: material-science, x-ray-crystallography, raman-spectroscopy

I am currently trying to analyse a [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b08449) in which perovskite material is pressurized and they observe the variation in structural properties using Synchrotron XRD and Raman Spectroscopy. Now the intersting thing is that at 3.3 GPa according to the raman spectra a new phase can be seen.

[image]

But according to the XRD data no phase shift is observed at 3.3 GPa (they do observe a phase shift which is consistent in both XRD and Raman but that is easy to understand so not going to ask about that)

[image]

As can be seen from above graph, no change is observed at 3.3 GPa.

What is the reason this is happening? Does the structure remain the same but the only difference with more pressure than 3.3 GPa is the fact that there are just not vibrations present now which could be attributed to something like ionic nature? Or is the structure also changing but the XRD is not sensitive enough to catch this change?